# parsing and replacing multiple lines with sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace blocks of 3 lines with sed and I'm running into a weird problem … the script I'm using is

```
/^#begin$/N;N;s/#begin\n\(.*\)\n#end/replaced \1/
```

On an input file that looks like

```
#begin
1
#end
```

it works fine and I get

```
replaced 1
```

However, if there is a line before the block the parse fails … the same script applied to

```
a line
#begin
1
#end
```

does not change anything. If I add two lines (say "a line" followed by "another line"), it works again … I can't understand why.
Any thoughts ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{ .. }` around the action on specific pattern:

```
/^#begin$/{N;N;s/#begin\n\(.*\)\n#end/replaced \1/}
```

For eg:

```
$ cat file
a line
#begin
1
#end
```

```
$ sed '/^#begin$/{N;N;s/#begin\n\(.*\)\n#end/replaced \1/}' file
a line
replaced 1
```

Some versions of `sed` (BSD) require a trailing `;` before the end brace. So use the following:

```
sed '/^#begin$/{N;N;s/#begin\n\(.*\)\n#end/replaced \1/;}' file
```

Comment: I tried that, but if I add those the script breaks with the error "bad flag in substitute command: '}'"

Comment: What version of `sed` are you using? What `OS`? You probably need a trailing `;` before the closing brace.

Comment: this is on Mac OSX 10.7.5, and I can't find out about the version for some reason … "-v" and "--version" fail. But the trailing ";" made it, thanks a lot ! I also just compiled sed 4.2.1 and it accepts the "}" without the trailing ";".

Comment: @user3692103 You're welcome. Thats right, `BSD` variants of `sed` require a trailing `;`. Will add that to the answer since it helped.

Answer (score 0):

For anything involving multiple lines, you're better of with awk. e.g with GNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub():

```
$ gawk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{$0=gensub(/#begin\n([^\n]+)\n#end/,"replaced \\1","")}1' file
a line
replaced 1
```

Comment: in this particular case I have to do it with sed. Using the brackets solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/#begin/,/#end/c\replaced 1' file
```

Comment: well, the example I posted is a simplified version, in practice there are things in-between the begin and end markers which necessitate special treatments. The bracket solution proposed above works fine for that.