# Delete blank line and Inserting multiple lines with bash & sed - deleting single blank line before match

Tags: linux, bash, sed, insert, sh

Attempting to insert

> host: localhost
>
> port: 5432
>
> username: postgres
>
> password: postgres

into a database.yml file with a bash script, I've been Finally had some success. Here is the script so far:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

/^development:/i\ \ host: localhost\n  port: 5432\n  username: postgres\n  password: postgres
```

But it still leaves a blank line before the input. How can I delete this within the same bash file? The final thing I need now is to have the output go from

```
Line
Line 

host: localhost   
port: 5432   
username: postgres
```

to:

```
Line
Line     
host: localhost   
port: 5432   
username: postgres
```

using a search and match parameter within the same bash file above.

Comment: You specified `#!/bin/sed -f` in the shebang, and then you called the command `sed` itself, which does not exist in `sed` (interpreted as command `s`)

Comment: Do you want to output the change, or actually edit the file in place? If the latter, `ed` would be much simpler syntactically.

Comment: That said, inserting data into a YAML file based on a line number is brittle.

Comment: You should look for questions about **insert multiple lines with sed** you would see your question is already answer in quite a number of threads like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270611/parsing-and-replacing-multiple-lines-with-sed

Comment: I am trying to output the result to screen so i can confirm its correct and then change it to edit the file. 
I tried the above advice and am still struggling. can someone please help me out? Im a sed noob, and I've already spent like 5 hours on this.

Comment: Try `sed '23s/^/host: localhost\n  port: 5432\n  username: postgres\n  password: postgres\n/' database.yml`

Comment: AND then, if the output you get from WalterA's comment is correct, edit that line to include `sed -i ....` . If you are using a Mac, then you'll need `sed -i'' ...` The `-i` (`--inplace`) is well documented and a search here for `[sed] --inplace` should give you many QA where this is discussed. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could not make your code work for myself (I think it's missing some) so I just rewrote what you needed in a much simpler way. Let us know why you need to use `sed`, if any:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: postgres
  password: postgres" > database.yml
```

This will simply create the file you need. You don't need `sed` for this. About your next two questions, if you want to remove the first blank line, you can use the following `sed` command :

```
sed -i '1d' database.yml
```

Replace `1` with the line number you want to delete. And for your last question, if you know which line number is empty, you can use the above `sed` command, but if not, the following can help you:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' database.yml
```

Will remove all of the blank lines inside database.yml file. You can achieve the same with `awk` as well (Read more about `awk` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)):

```
awk 'NF' database.yml > database1.yml
```

You can remove only the first blank like using `awk` like below :

```
awk 'NR!=1' database.yml > database1.yml
```

Note that you cannot output `awk` to the same file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks aLuVian, that gets me one step closer, I think what you misunderstood is that database.yml is a larger file not just the text you echoed or that i posted.
when i enter my script above to automatically select database.yml (at the end of my code in the sed script

I get "/bin/sed: file ./edit2.sh line 5: unterminated `s' command" 
Im not even specifying the s command, its just getting confused when i put

#!/bin/sed -f

/^development:/i\ \ host: localhost\n  port: 5432\n  username: postgres#\n  password: postgres database.yml

Comment: @Soloff Sorry I could not understand your problem completely. Please update your question with a more complete version of database.yml (you don't have to put the whole file, if that's big) and your script file, plus the error, so I can update my answer based on your exact problem and hopefully,  resolve it.